# Lravel 5 export to csv date issue?

Tags: php, laravel-5

i am trying export data into csv using laravel lumen and for Ui i am using  angular2. i have date field which is of type datetime . because of that i am not able to export data from UI ,it gives error as No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

here is the php code

```
public function exportOrderData($request){
    $vm = new ViewModels\Response();
    $orders = $this->model->select('order_number','customer_orders.customer_id', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'order_date','status','total','discount')
    ->leftJoin('client_customers', 'client_customers.customer_id', '=', 'customer_orders.customer_id')
    ->where('customer_orders.client_id',$request->user()->client_id)->get();
    if($orders){
        $vm->data = $orders->toArray();

// $data['order_date']="17-06-2017" => if i hardcore this it wont work
// $data['order_date']="sample" =>if i hardcore like this it will work
    }
    else{
        $vm->errors[] = ['property'=>'export', 'message'=>'Cannot export orders data'];
    }
    return $vm;
}
```

how can i return date?

Comment: please try this way `$data['order_date']="'17-06-2017'"`

Comment: Why does the `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header` relate to a date field?

Comment: $data['order_date']="'17-06-2017'"  this is not working

Comment: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header no idea about this error

Comment: You have no `$data` variable defined in that function. Did you mean to do `$vm->data[...]` ?

Comment: can you add more details?